# No refresh token or refresh handler callback is set in nodejs authentification system

Tags: node.js

I am trying to send Email using `Nodemailer and OAuth2 in nodejs` but i am getting an weird error :

> concerning accesstoken method in sendmail file

Here is sendmail.js file:

```
    oauth2Client.setCredentials({
        refresh_token: MAILING_SERVICE_REFRESH_TOKEN
    })

    const accessToken = oauth2Client.getAccessToken()
    const smtpTransport = nodemailer.createTransport({
        service: 'gmail',
        auth: {
            type: 'OAuth2',
            user: SENDER_EMAIL_ADDRESS,
            clientId: MAILING_SERVICE_CLIENT_ID,
            clientSecret: MAILING_SERVICE_CLIENT_SECRET,
            refreshToken: MAILING_SERVICE_REFRESH_TOKEN,
            accessToken
        }
    })
```

I am getting the following error:

> No refresh token or refresh handler callback is set.
> at OAuth2Client.getAccessTokenAsync (C:\Users\DELL\Desktop\events\api\node_modules\google-auth-library\build\src\auth\oauth2client.js:224:27)
> at OAuth2Client.getAccessToken (C:\Users\DELL\Desktop\events\api\node_modules\google-auth-library\build\src\auth\oauth2client.js:209:25)
> at sendEmail (C:\Users\DELL\Desktop\events\api\routes\sendmail.js:26:38)
> at C:\Users\DELL\Desktop\events\api\routes\auth.js:41:7 [nodemon] app crashed - waiting for file changes before starting...

It returns a success response in postman but the server crashes and the mail is not send.
Hope you can help and thanks in advance